# Combining Pictures of Letters

Tags: inkscape, pictures

I am trying to put 3 letters next to each other. These Letters are saved as Images, unfortunately I don't know yet how to make the pictures just the the outline of the letter and not a box containing the letter, so that I could push them so close together in order for them to touch each other

Many thanks for your help!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If they are raster images which have black on a white background you can give to them in the Objects panel Blending mode =Multiply. Then they can overlap. White causes nothing and black in one image makes that point black.

You can also goto GIMP and turn in your bitmaps all white to transparency. You must add an alpha channel to your image to make transparency possible and apply Color to Alpha so that white is converted to transparency. Save as  PNG and import to Inkscape.

I must admit your case is a puzzle. If you can write texts with a font in your computer you should also be able to have the texts as vectors. I have met the same problem as you when I copied a piece of text as screenshot (no other way available then) I tried also to do Trace Bitmap to get a vector, but quite low resolution and antialiasing made it useless. The text looked best as a bitmap.

If the letter images already happen to be vectors the blend mode = multiply -trick  still works, but as well you should be able to kill the white area by disassembling the image and deleting all white. Impossible to give exact steps without seeing the vector structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you've tried, but the steps are pretty straight forward.
Each image should be traced, using Path, Trace Bitmap.

If necessary, use Path, Break Apart which will separate the individual objects. You can then select the groups of objects you wish to cluster and Group them.

You'll then be able to move each group to the desired locations.

Note that after you trace each image, you'll still have the image floating about behind the newly created vectors.